# how to push a single java file to a remote repository

Tags: bash, github

I am new in git and want to push some java files to remote github repository. The files are NOT a project, just some algorithm problems that I want to share on github.

When I tried `git push` the alert `fatal: not a git repository: .git`

Is there any quick way to push some/single file to repo using git bash? thanks

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to do a `git init .` in the folder whare your files are.
Then add the github repo as a remote:

```
git remote add origin https://<yourLogin>@github.com/<yourLogin>/<yourRepo>
git add .
git commit -m "My first files"
git push -u origin master
```

---

The other approach, especially if the remote repo on GitHub is not empty (because of `README` and `LICENSE` files), is to clone that repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/<yourLogin>/<yourRepo>
cd <yourRepo>
# copy your files there
git add .
git commit -m "My first files"
git push -u origin master
```